# Can I get a compile error on potential null ptr dereference - in Go?

Tags: go, null, compiler-warnings

A colleague has a null ptr dereference in Go.

I advised him to do as I would do - working in other languages, I tend to crank the warning level high and turn warnings into errors. In e.g. C#, that means I cannot compile this code:

```
private static string bad_deref(object? Object)
{
    return Object.ToString();
}
```

because I get

```
  x.cs(y,z): [CS8602] Dereference of a possibly null reference.
```

Which, to be clear, is very good.

But he tells me Go doesn't *have* a warning level to crank and, googling, it would appear he is right.

So how do you solve this problem in Go? Are we back to good old C advice "good programmers don't make mistakes" and null ptr dereferences just sometimes happen if you don't work with perfect people?

Comment: Besides what icza wrote there's also this: https://staticcheck.io/docs/checks#SA5011, though I haven't used the tool myself so I can't vouch for how useful it is in reality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct: you can't make a compiler error out of dereferencing a pointer without handling a `nil` case. That's because the language spec allows it. Nothing you can do about it.

You can write bad / incorrect code in any language, and the mean to detect errors early or mitigate them is to write tests in almost all languages.

Go has a nice [testing framework](https://pkg.go.dev/testing) built into the `go` tool itself. You should definitely take advantage of it. Write tests whenever / wherever appropriate. Go tests should be executed on a regular basis, they are automatically run during CI/CD and before releases. Most IDEs also run tests on save automatically.

Another trick you may use: if the `nil` pointer makes no sense, write an API that uses non-pointer type. Of course this has its drawbacks (sometimes pointers are a must); if using pointer makes more sense, use it, but check for `nil` values, and handle them properly (e.g. return an `error`, panic if that makes sense etc.). Also write tests to test with `nil` pointer values.

Comment: "You can write bad / incorrect code in any language" well, I cannot write this *specific* type of bad code in C# because Microsoft knows it's a very common error pattern and built detection into the compiler - but I'll believe you that Go has no analysis for this and accept the answer. (Edit: In 3 minutes when I'm allowed)

Comment: @SRNissen Yes, there must be a compromise between fast compilation and the checks the compiler does for you. You can write an `AddIntegers()` function, which if returns `a - b` instead of `a + b`, that's 99.99% an error, yet none of the compilers check _this_ specific case.